# android google maps nullpointerexception

Tags: android, google-maps, nullpointerexception, supportmapfragment

So I've been seeing a peculiar exception coming from what I'm pretty sure is Google Maps drawing code.

I've got a Fragment, where I programatically add in a SupportMapFragment, and then I manipulate the GoogleMap instance within it.

Here's the stacktrace:

```
0   java.lang.NullPointerException

1   at java.nio.ReadWriteDirectByteBuffer.put(ReadWriteDirectByteBuffer.java:137)

2   at java.nio.ShortToByteBufferAdapter.put(ShortToByteBufferAdapter.java:163)

3   at maps.z.d.d(Unknown Source)

4   at maps.z.d.a(Unknown Source)

5   at maps.aq.a.a(Unknown Source)

6   at maps.aq.ao.b(Unknown Source)

7   at maps.aq.ao.a(Unknown Source)

8   at maps.v.g.a(Unknown Source)

9   at maps.v.g.b(Unknown Source)

10  at maps.p.p.l(Unknown Source)

11  at maps.p.p.run(Unknown Source)
```

I can't reliably replicate it (although it's happening quite often), I've looked at ReadWriteDirectByteBuffer and ShortToByteBufferAdapter but nothing pops out at me.

Any ideas?

Comment: I've come with a workaround for this. It's not a fix but at least avoids having the app crash all the time. Check out my own answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19624437/random-nullpointerexception-on-google-maps-api-v2/19627149#19627149

Answer (score 4):

I have had the same random problem.

You may want to try to ressurect the [issue on gmaps-api-issues](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=5100).

Comment: Crazy, I saw your response when I searched for the stack trace online. I went and added a response, hope there's some insight shed there.

Comment: Still getting this. Starred and commented on the issue as well.

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem and found it was fixed in my app by implementing the .onPause() method of the mapView in the onPause() method of the Fragment the MapView was in.

I think you need to implement all these methods within the Fragment and ensure they are called on your MapView.

```
MapView mapView; 

@Override
public void onResume() {
    mapView.onResume();
    super.onResume();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    mapView.onDestroy();
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    mapView.onPause();
}

@Override
public void onLowMemory() {
    super.onLowMemory();
    mapView.onLowMemory();
}
```

I see that the original poster talks of using a Fragment within a Fragment. I am using MapView within a Fragment instead. See this post for how to do this: [Android - android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20919048/android-android-view-inflateexception-binary-xml-file-line-8-error-inflatin/20971284#20971284)

Comment: Not sure where i found the code, but i only had the onResume onDestroy and onLowMemory and this problem keep happening. After adding onPause the problem got solved. Ty!

Comment: but  i have mapfragment not mapview then how ??