# DirectByteBufferException whale fetching different maps in fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, maps

I am creating an app that fetches 2 or three maps and show them in a viewpager. **sometimes** it crashes and show the below errors.

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 2477
    java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.nio.DirectByteBuffer.put(DirectByteBuffer.java:344)
    at java.nio.ByteBufferAsShortBuffer.put(ByteBufferAsShortBuffer.java:160)
    at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.o.c.a.d.d(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.o.c.a.d.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.o.a.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.o.c.b(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.o.c.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.o.l.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.o.l.b(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.o.cw.k(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.o.cw.run(Unknown Source)
```

there is no info about the cause of this error in logcat. i am unable to trace the error.
what can be the possible causes of this error and how can i resolve this.

Comment: See link below:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19624437/random-nullpointerexception-on-google-maps-api-v2/19627149#19627149

Comment: Looks like Google is aware of the issue: https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=5100

Comment: @GaganpreetSingh What works for you ?

Answer (score 1):

I had an issue with the same stacktrace when I were using `MapView` in custom fragment (not `MapFragment`), however I weren't using ViewPager.
It turns out that I forgot to call `MapView.onPause()`, while called all other `MapView` lifecycle callbacks.
Adding this block fixed the issue in my case:

```
@Override
public void onPause() {
    mapView.onPause();
    super.onPause();
}
```

Comment: kindly gave solution for map fragment , i am not using mapview

Comment: am facing this problem when using two map in one activity one is 2d map and other is street view map